# Add div using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, image, slider

I would like to add this div using JQuery on front of an image, which I will find it using the alt attribute of the image because the image is inside a slider.The image does not have an #id. I'm using wordpress.

```
<div>
<h2>SEO</h2>
<span>Conquer the SEO</span>
<a class="btn" title="Read More" href="#">Read More</a>
</div>
```

My slider HTML:

```
<div id="P_MS55ad3a788b28c" class="master-slider-parent msl ms-parent-id-5"  >


    <div id="MS55ad3a788b28c" class="master-slider ms-skin-light-6 round-skin" >

        <div  class="ms-slide" data-delay="3" data-fill-mode="fill"  >
            <img src="http://localhost/inncha/wp-content/plugins/master-slider/public/assets/css/blank.gif" alt="" title="" data-src="http://localhost/inncha/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/06.jpg" />


        <div class="ms-thumb" ><div class="ms-tab-context"><div class=&quot;ms-tab-context&quot;></div></div></div></div>
                    <div  class="ms-slide" data-delay="3" data-fill-mode="fill"  >
                        <img src="http://localhost/inncha/wp-content/plugins/master-slider/public/assets/css/blank.gif" alt="facebook" title="" data-src="http://localhost/inncha/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/011.jpg" />


        <div class="ms-thumb" ><div class="ms-tab-context"><div class=&quot;ms-tab-context&quot;></div></div></div></div>
                    <div  class="ms-slide" data-delay="3" data-fill-mode="fill"  >
                        <img src="http://localhost/inncha/wp-content/plugins/master-slider/public/assets/css/blank.gif" alt="Ιστοσελίδες" title="" data-src="http://localhost/inncha/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/021.jpg" />


        <div class="ms-thumb" ><div class="ms-tab-context"><div class=&quot;ms-tab-context&quot;></div></div></div></div>
                    <div  class="ms-slide" data-delay="3" data-fill-mode="fill"  >
                        <img src="http://localhost/inncha/wp-content/plugins/master-slider/public/assets/css/blank.gif" alt="εταιρική ταυτότητα" title="" data-src="http://localhost/inncha/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/05.jpg" />


        <div class="ms-thumb" ><div class="ms-tab-context"><div class=&quot;ms-tab-context&quot;></div></div></div></div>

    </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Please provide slider HTML... Your scenario has some flaws, you actually need image container element (or to create new one) - because of div position....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier to answer this if you had posted your HTML, but I'll  do my best.

Once you have found your target image, you can use [`.position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) to calculate its positions. Then I would clone a hidden `<div>`, append to the parent of the image, and position it absolutely on top of your image at the specified position.

```js
$(function() {
  //find the target image
  var image = $('[alt="My Image"]');
  
  //save the position
  var position = image.position();
  
  //target the first instance of your hidden div, position it, add opacity, and append to the parent
  $(".seo").eq(0).clone().show().css({
    position: "absolute",
    top: position.top,
    left: position.left,
    opacity: 0.9
  }).appendTo(image.parent());
});
```

```css
.seo { display : none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="seo">
  <h2>SEO</h2>
  <span>Conquer the SEO</span>
<a class="btn" title="Read More" href="#">Read More</a>
</div>

<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="My Image" />
```

Comment: You are very fast. Thank you Dave. That works but I would like the div to be on top of each slide(on top meaning in z-axel -> on front maybe more correct(I'll correct it in the top)

Comment: Did you run the snippet? The div is positioned in front of the image.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I've included the last img tag as well. The div sits at the top of the image of all the slides. I guess I'll have to put it inside the php of the slider to work correctly

Comment: I've changed the class name and forgot to change it on the div, that's why it was not working! Thank you for your help Dave!